# Creating conditional sums (based on dates) as new column of data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to do some feature engineering in R. Let's assume I have the following dataframe:

```
events = data.frame(patient = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"), 
                    date = as.Date(c("2017-12-15", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-31", "2018-02-05", 
                                     "2017-12-12", "2017-12-12", "2018-02-01")), 
                    type = c("AnE","Inpatient","Inpatient","Inpatient","AnE","AnE",
                             "Inpatient"))`
```

I now want to add a column with the sum of "Inpatient" events from the same patient in the previous 30 days.

Is there a straight-forward way of doing this (that doesn't involve for loops)?

Comment: What should the output look like? what is your expected results?

Comment: It should look like this: 
    events$SumPrevInpatient = c(0,0,1,2,0,0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data set I would create some handle variables and run a data.table approach.

First I add the date of last period by patient. Then, I sum how many times "Inpatient" appears in the data set by patient and dates of last period that are sooner than 30 days from the current date.

```
library(data.table)
events = data.table(patient = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"), 
                    date = as.Date(c("2017-12-15", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-31", "2018-02-05", 
                                     "2017-12-12", "2017-12-12", "2018-02-01")), 
                    type = c("AnE","Inpatient","Inpatient","Inpatient","AnE","AnE",
                             "Inpatient"))
events = events[order(date), .SD, by = patient]
events[, date_t1 := lag(date), by = patient]
events[, timesInpatient := cumsum(type=="Inpatient"), by = .(patient, date_t1 > date - 30)]
```

The result looks like this

```
   patient       date      type      date1 timesInpatient
1:       B 2017-12-12       AnE       <NA>              0
2:       B 2017-12-12       AnE 2017-12-12              0
3:       B 2018-02-01 Inpatient 2017-12-12              1
4:       A 2017-12-15       AnE       <NA>              0
5:       A 2018-01-09 Inpatient 2017-12-15              1
6:       A 2018-01-31 Inpatient 2018-01-09              2
7:       A 2018-02-05 Inpatient 2018-01-31              3
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. I hadn't considered using data.table.

Comment: Oh, just a minor thing: I actually just want the sum of **previous** events. I'm assuming the easiest way to do this is adding `date_t1 < date` to the last line.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little less terse than the `data.table` approach, but you could potentially use `span` and `%within%` from the `lubridate` package.

Here's an example of how they work:

```
# creating a span object and a vector of dates
span <- lubridate::interval("2018-01-01", "2018-01-30")
dates <- as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-30", "2018-01-03", "2018-02-01"))
dates %within% span
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# adding a vector indicating inpatient visits
inpatient_visit <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)
# counting dates are both fall within the span and are inpatient visits
sum(dates %within% span & visit)
[1] 2
```

You could then use a [split-apply-combine approach](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) (using `split` and `purrr:map_df`) and repeat this counting process for each patient in your dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

events = data.frame(patient = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B"), 
                    date = as.Date(c("2017-12-15", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-31", "2018-02-05", 
                                     "2017-12-12", "2017-12-12", "2018-02-01")), 
                    type = c("AnE","Inpatient","Inpatient","Inpatient","AnE","AnE",
                             "Inpatient"))

count_visits <- function(df) {
  res <- map(df$span, ~ sum(df$date %within% .x & df$inpatient))
  df$count <- res
  return(df)
}

events <- events %>%
  mutate(inpatient = type == "Inpatient",
         span = interval(date - days(30), date)) %>%
  split(.$patient) %>%
  map_df(count_visits) %>%
  select(-inpatient, -span) %>%
  arrange(date)

events
  patient       date      type count
1       B 2017-12-12       AnE     0
2       B 2017-12-12       AnE     0
3       A 2017-12-15       AnE     0
4       A 2018-01-09 Inpatient     1
5       A 2018-01-31 Inpatient     2
6       B 2018-02-01 Inpatient     1
7       A 2018-02-05 Inpatient     3
```